# how do i access my cisco router details from ios mobile

Tags: ios, api, mobile, dll, router

Is it possible to access my Cisco **router details** like Name,Model,IP Address,Connection status etc from my iOS mobile.

I'm even ready to write small mobile app in iOS to get all router details.
Since I have just started learning in iOS, don't know if any **library** already exists for above task.
If my router does not work or gets hang.. I even want to try for restart of router using my mobile.

If **example code** exist, it will be very useful.

Like Cisco already has andriod and iOS app for same above function but dont want to use this app and want to write my own app with limited features only.
(http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/cisco-connect-express-manage-router-settings-remotely-android-ios/)

Thanks,

Comment: do u want to restart ur router from ur mobile app ?

Comment: What kind of router?  Cisco has some API's available, [such as the "Guest Access API"](https://developer.cisco.com/web/gap/home)... but I don't know if the tiny home routers actually support this.

Comment: i hv small home router. With "Guest Acces API" will i be able to restart the router ?

Comment: Read through these, may be you can find something.. http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/interfaces_modules/services_modules/ax/1-5/developer/guide/axpdevel/axpapi1.html#wp1027723  http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/interfaces_modules/services_modules/ax/1-5/developer/guide/axpdevel/axpapif.html

Answer (score 1):

Accessing network gear is best done by using SNMP. Cisco has extremely rich management/monitoring capabilities via SNMP and all of their MIBs are publicly available [here](http://www.cisco.com/public/sw-center/netmgmt/cmtk/mibs.shtml).

Almost all Cisco gear supports the `SNMPv2-SMI` MIB (the 1.3.6.1.2.1 OID) so querying things like sysName, sysLocation, sysContact, sysDescription, sysUpTime should be very easy. This MIB even supports tables for listing all the interfaces and IP addresses and has a whole lot of other things that might be of interest to you.

If you have SNMP write access on the device then you can even make config changes and perform management functions like rebooting or bringing an interface up/down.

There are a few SNMP libraries for ObjectiveC and I think [Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/) is the most popular (It's not .net even though the title suggests that).

If you are new to SNMP then I suggest starting simple by querying easy objects like `1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5` (sysName) and `1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6` (sysLocation) before trying to jump into tables like `1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2` (ifTable)

Remember, you don't have to stick with the standard MIBs you can download all of the custom ones that are particular to your device which will give you incredible amounts of flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a screen-scraping technique to telnet or ssh to the Cisco device and parse the "show version" output. This will give you some of the information you need. For others, like IP addresses, you can use "show ip interface brief", "show cdp neighbors" etc. as you need.

Keep security in mind: make sure that telnet/ssh credentials are adequately protected in your app's settings, and try to restrict your commands to those that do not need privileged access on the Cisco device.

Be aware that Cisco devices have a small pool of available VTYs, and every telnet/ssh access from your app will use up one VTY. So if you have for example 30 guys wanting to use the access the device simultaneously from their apps, some of those instances are not going to get access to the device.

If this is a concern, SNMP is a better and more scalable option as suggested by previous answer. Make sure that you (a) have a read-only community string configured on the device, and (b) use only the ro community string from the app.